# Trouble with WMI filter

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-2.0, wmi-query

I've got a notepad.exe started in my session :

```
gwmi -Query "Select CommandLine from Win32_Process where CommandLine='C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe'"
```

gives

```
Get-WmiObject : Demande non valide
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 5
+ gwmi <<<<  -Query "Select CommandLine from Win32_Process where CommandLine='C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe'"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand
```

I test :

```
gwmi -Query "Select CommandLine from Win32_Process where CommandLine='C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe'"
```

It gives nothing

```
gwmi -Query "Select CommandLine from Win32_Process where CommandLine LIKE '%C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe%'"
```

Works perfectly

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_Process
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        :
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
CommandLine      : "C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe"
```

Perhaps it's a trouble with wildcards caracters between PowerShell and WMI, but anyone can help me make filter `CommandLine='C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe'` working

Comment: What's the value of `CommandLine` on the found (when found) `Win32_Process` instance? Eg. here the `CommandLine` value includes double quotes.

Comment: I Edit the question to show the value if th propertie when it works.
If you look at WMBEMTEST.EXE `CommandLine` is one ofthe properties of `WIN32_Process`.

Comment: the issue is that CommandLine is surrounded by ". how escape " in gwmi query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the CommandLine property contains quotes, so they need to be escaped as well.

A working, but horrible string is:

```
gwmi -Query "Select * from Win32_Process where CommandLine = '`"c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe`"'"
```

Comment: have you tested it? return nothing!

Comment: I turn arroud it, thanks that just what I was looking for. Ijust don't see that there were "" in WBEMTEST.EXE.

Comment: @craika: sure! but for me return nothing! why now?

Comment: @Christian It works for me too, don't you forgot to start a notepad before running test ? ;o) I just copy past.

Comment: @JPBlanc: sure! but for me return nothing! why now?

Comment: @Chistian: x64 vs 32 maybe? 32-bit notepad path in 64-bit PowerShell is in SysWOW?

Comment: @craika: nope, i'm on an XP x32 box. I'm gone mad... before your answer i had escape with backtricks but doesn't works... why??

Comment: Now test on Seven, Server W2K8R2 and Windows 8 (PowerShell 3) work in all three, sorry @Christian

Comment: INCREDIBLE! in my box commandLine have an extra space after last quote: '(backtricks)"c:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe(backtricks)" '".

Comment: I just encountered the same on a Seven ! I reproduce it when launching notepad via 'search' entry in start menu!

Comment: a mistery issue. On my box always the same, launching by link or original notepad.exe. thank you for reporting to me your test!

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the quotes, but as I can't recall how to escape them in WQL, I would do it in PSH:

```
gwmi -class Win32_Process -filter "CommandLine like '`"C:\\Windows\\system32\\notepad.exe`"'"
```

Filter expression is in double quotes, with the string argument to `LIKE` in single quotes. The double quotes that are part of that argument need to be quoted from PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-Process | ? {$_.Path -eq 'C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe'}

Get-Process | ? {$_.processname -eq 'notepad'}
```